# Using Multiple Mail Servers for single domain

Tags: dns, sendgrid, mail-server, mx-record, amazon-simple-email-service

I've setup two mail servers 
 1. Gmail sever for handling certain email of my domain.com
 2. A custom sendgrid inbound parse that also accepts certain email for my domain.com

Now I've two MX records on DNS setting for both mail servers. but I see only one is working . That one works which priority is only 1. Even I tried setting both priority to 1 only one works.
How can I make it working send on both. 
Or can i create some custom service that forwards mail to mail server depending on from_email address ?

Answer (score 0):

Mail will always be sent to just 1 mailserver, which is chosen by the priorities of your MX records.

To be able to use 2 mailservers for 1 domain you can have a look at Split-Domain Routing (SDR)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to handle this to have your gmail on your primary domain.com and sendgrid on your subdomain something like notification.domain.com so that you can send and receive emails using sendgrid (xxx@notification.domain.com) and using gmail (xxx@domain.com). You can have MX records of Gmail corresponding to host domain.com and CNAME records for sendgrid corresponding to the host notification.domain.com.